# Hive - Insert string into table

Tags: hadoop, hive

I tried to load data from S3 and the unload table looks like:

```
date_id             string                  from deserializer
order_id                string                  from deserializer
```

...

The format of date_id is "yyyyMMdd", and order_id is definitely a string.

But when I tried to create a new table like and try to insert the data from unload table to the new table, the value of these columns shows NULL.

```
New table:
-----------------
date_id             date                
order_id                string
```

...

Query:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE new table
PARTITION (date_id)
SELECT  
CAST(TO_DATE(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(DATE_ID, 'yyyyMMdd'))) as DATE) as DATE_ID,
BATCH_ID AS BATCH_ID,
...
FROM
Unload_table
```

Does anybody know why it shows NULL for the two fields? How to insert the value into the new table?

Thanks!

Comment: it will be good if you provide more clarification, in your Insert as select command, you have used partition column as date_id, but for your cast statement you are using a different column DIM_DATE_ID with alias DIM_DATE , is  your intention is to cast date_id from string to date and partition over it , if so was it done in your query , since you dint post the complete query?

Comment: @Addy I think the other field is not related with the problem. I edited the query in the question and right now there's no unrelated fields.